# Choosing the bullet of a single item in Easylist

Tags: easylist

Since I could not find a sufficiently customizable note taking software, I have decided to make a LaTeX template for doing so. I found the EasyList package suggested for creating lists fast, but I could not change the bullet-type of a single item.

So my question is, can we change the bullet type of a single item in EasyList by specifying it within the declaration of that line only?

For example

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
    & This is a bullet
    & This is also a bullet
    & Can I make only this one to be a check-box? Maybe through something like &[checkbox]
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want different symbols for each item in an `easylist` then I think that you need to set different symbols for each list level. To get this to work you need to: hide the counters, turn off the indentation and then use `Style` to specify each symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
  \ListProperties(Hide=100,Progressive=0cm,%
      Style1*=\textbullet,%
      Style2*=$\ast$,%
      Style3*=$\square$)
  & First thingy    % a bullet
  & Second thingy   % another bullet
  &&& Third thingy  % a square
  && Fourth thingy  % a *  
\end{easylist}    
\end{document}
```

Sorry, it´s tricky to post images from this computer, but this works. The spacing after the symbols needs some help, but there are examples in the manual so you should be able to sort it out.

Another way to do it is to insert a line like

```
\ListProperties(Style1*=\#)
```

into your `easylist` whenever you want to change the symbol.

I agree that neither of these options is particularly easy, but I guess that the author of the package didn´t think of this particular use case.

Comment: The second way is actually very easy! Thanks a lot.