# Using Easylist and leaving one entry bullet blank

Tags: formatting, easylist

So I have a checklist using the checkboxes. I want to make occasional ones not have the check box because there are several indented checkboxes I want to choose from.
I see [Choosing the bullet of a single item in Easylist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187616/choosing-the-bullet-of-a-single-item-in-easylist)

Which gets me very close with the second one: `\ListProperties(Style1*=)`

So, how do I go back to the checkboxes? Google hasn't helped me find what the style name would be for the checkboxes again.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multienum}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}[checklist]
@ First thing
@ Thing I want indented but no checkbox
@@ Sub things I want with checkbox
@@ Sub things I want with checkbox
@ New thing I want with checkbox
@ Another thing I want without checkbox
@@ Another thing I want without checkbox
@@@ Sub thing with checkbox
@@@ Sub thing with checkbox
@@ Another thing without checkbox
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

I've added the example latex with easylist. I've listed what I want to do I think...

This is the current output

[image: Current Output]

This is what I want

[image: What I want]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass..\begin{document}..\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: Use something like `\noindent First thingy    % None
  && second second second
  & Second thingy   % another bullet`. Just don't put `&` and issue a `\noindent`.

Comment: If i do \noindent, then the "Thing I want indented but no checkbox" ends up on the same line as "First thing"

Answer (score 1):

While this answer does not use easylist, I think it does what it is you want really.

The first solution is to have a standalone-macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\myboxcmd{mom}{%
    \indent\hspace{#1} \IfValueT{#2}{$\Box$}\IfValueF{#2}{\phantom{$\Box$}} #3\hfill\break
}
\begin{document}
    \myboxcmd{1em}[]{Title}
    \myboxcmd{2em}{Title}
    \myboxcmd{2em}[]{Title}
    \myboxcmd{3em}{Title}
    \myboxcmd{3em}[]{Title}
\end{document}
```

This command takes a first mandatory argument which is the indentation you want, the second is optional and by just including it will give you a box. The third is mandatory and is the title.

The second solution gives you a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{checkbox}{description}{1}
\setlist[checkbox]{font=\normalfont,leftmargin=2em}
\NewDocumentCommand\aBox{omm}{%
    \item[\hspace{#2}\IfValueT{#1}{$\Box$}\IfValueF{#1}{\phantom{$\Box$}}] #3
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{checkbox}
        \aBox[]{1em}{Test}
        \aBox[]{2em}{Test}
        \aBox{2em}{Test}
        \aBox[]{2em}{Test}
    \end{checkbox}

\end{document}
```

Here, the first argument is optional and gives you the box by just including it, the second argument is the indentation you want, the third is the title.

While not using easylist, this seems to give you what I think you were asking for. 
[image: Results]